# Site nav bar (hamburger) now unresponsive on smartphones?

Tags: responsive

Our previously functional site navigation has become unresponsive on smartphones. (Possibly because of changes made to please Google PageSpeed.) The menu switches over to the 'hamburger' on small screens, and it gives visual feedback when touched, but nav menu options do not display. Plus, I cannot duplicate this in the Chrome development tools. Tips?

[link to site with problem on phones](http://luke5marketing.com/)

Comment: No, it's just your site, and quite probably because of W3 Total Cache minify settings. Anyways, implementation issues are off topic here, try StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This almost certainly has nothing to do with PageSpeed.

I'd start here, you have a jQuery is undefined error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at 2ad36.default.include-footer.911778.js:22
```

This is off topic, but I agree with Devin. Could definitely be a W3 Total Cache issue. Try disabling it and see if it fixes your problem.

If you've installed any plugins recently, try disabling them one by one to narrow down any issues caused by them.

That's really the best anyone can tell you to do tbh.